# How can I remove snaps without losing GUI?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning

I want to know how to check how many snaps programs/apps I'm running. Also, how to replace them (if possible) without losing GUI?

Comment: `snap list` is a command which will list your installed snaps.  `sudo snap remove <snappackage>` will remove a snap package, but I'd look first to see what's there (I doubt you'd have any that would impact your gui)

Answer (score 4):

If here GUI means Desktop Environment, then no you won't lose that if you uninstall any Snap. Snap package is just another approach for distributing applications apart from other package types(like deb, rpm, etc).

- To know installed snaps:

  ```bsh
  snap list
  ```
- To install a new snap:

  ```bsh
  snap install <snap name> #Might need some flags like --classic
  ```
- To uninstall a snap:

  ```bsh
  snap remove <snap name>
  ```
- To update installed snaps:

  ```bsh
  snap refresh
  ```
- To search for snap:

  ```bsh
  snap search <snap name>
  ```

Snaps are mounted as loopback read-only squashfs filesystem. This increases boot time. If you don't like snaps and want to be completely dependent on APT or debs, you can uninstall that:

```bsh
sudo apt purge snapd
```